# What causes recovery log corruption, and what can be done about it?

Tags: websphere

Have checked the ServerErr.log and found the below given exception: Which is basically due to the corruption of log1 and log2 in tranlog and partnerlog location. What to know how does the log1 and log2 gets corrupt. Want to know the complete the procedure.

```
[3/22/16 8:07:44:489 EDT] 0000000a WsServerImpl E WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogCorruptedException
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:336)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:91)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogCorruptedException
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.TxServiceImpl.asynchRecoveryProcessingComplete(TxServiceImpl.java:2180)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.RecoveryManager.recoveryFailed(RecoveryManager.java:1740)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.RecoveryManager.run(RecoveryManager.java:2333)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:810)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogCorruptedException
    at com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.LogHandle.openLog(LogHandle.java:555)
    at com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.MultiScopeRecoveryLog.openLog(MultiScopeRecoveryLog.java:573)
    at com.ibm.ws.recoverylog.spi.RecoveryLogImpl.openLog(RecoveryLogImpl.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.RecoveryManager.run(RecoveryManager.java:2263)
```

Answer (score 0):

The log1 and log2 files under the `<profile_root>/tranlog` directory record information required for transaction recovery. The `partnerlog` files hold information on resources involved in a transaction. The problem occurring here has been documented by IBM at this Technote: [Application Server fails to start with CWRLS0009E error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21326492). According to the same document, IBM recommends using the 'Transaction=all' trace specification to identify the cause of the corruption.

If you are not running WebSphere Process Server (WPS) or IBM Business Process Manager (BPM), you can empty these transaction log files and start your server. You can use `cp /dev/null log1` on all the tranlog & partnerlog files. For WPS & BPM, you cannot delete these files because they contain operational information about the product itself. See [this link](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/168147/system-inconsistency-due-to-deleted-transaction-or.html) for more details.